Transactional for custom session factory
@Bean
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory() {
        SessionFactory sessionFactory;
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

        HikariConfig hikariConfig = new HikariConfig();
        hikariConfig.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        hikariConfig.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate");
        hikariConfig.setUsername("root");
        hikariConfig.setPassword("password");

        hikariConfig.setMinimumIdle(5);
        hikariConfig.setMaximumPoolSize(20);
        hikariConfig.setConnectionTimeout(30000);
        hikariConfig.setIdleTimeout(300000);
        hikariConfig.setMaxLifetime(1800000);

        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.current_session_context_class", "thread");
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");

        sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig)).scanPackages("com.entity").addProperties(configuration.getProperties()).buildSessionFactory();
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Override
@Transactional
public void save(HibernateTable obj) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    session.persist(obj);
}

this is giving error like this
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Calling method 'persist' is not valid without an active transaction (Current status: NOT_ACTIVE)
I want to utilize the @Transactional annotation while using my custom SessionFactory bean, without relying on configurations stored in application.properties.

Is class that contains save is spring bean?

it is a method in @Component class

Do you call the method from same class?

i am calling that method using commadLineRunner

Just to make sure. You don't instantiate that class in your code?

no, i did not instantiate that class

Why not use the application.properties. Seems like you are working around the framework instead of embracing it? For starters stop messing with the hibernate.current_session_context_class. But still not using what is being provided by Spring Boot seems like a waste to me.
